# Issue with using Underscore in Wordpress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, underscore

I have read in another SO post that Underscore.js is including in Wordpress by default. I am using it to test if a variable is defined but get this in the browser console:

```
pluginAdminPage.js:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at pluginAdminPage.js:32
(anonymous) @ pluginAdminPage.js:32

_.VERSION // .VERSION even autofills. So then the browser has the library imported?
"1.8.3"
```

The code it refers to:

```
if (_.isUndefined(module) === false) {
  module.exports.func = func;
}
```

Phpstorm lints _ and `isUndefined` yellow which may suggest a lack of library import.

I then tried to explicitly enqueue Underscore but this did not change the browser error messages:

```
function loadAdminScripts() {
  wp_register_style(
    'admin-style',
    plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__)
  );
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-style');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('underscore');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'loadAdminScripts');
```

What step(s) am I missing to get Underscore working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set it as a dependency for your script, this is the best way you can make sure, Underscore.js is loaded **before** your script (which means, the methods will be available).

```
function loadAdminScripts() {
  wp_register_style(
    'admin-style',
    plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__)
  );
  wp_register_script(
    'pluginAdminPage',
    plugins_url('pluginAdminPage.js', __FILE__),
    [
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
    ]
  );

  wp_enqueue_style('admin-style');
  wp_enqueue_script('pluginAdminPage');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'loadAdminScripts');
```

Check the [Code Reference on `wp_register_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I take it you are setting the scripts as dependencies of the stylesheet so they have priority? Is wp_enqueue_scripts() not that useful then?

Comment: @SeanDezoysa Sorry, seems I read your question too quickly. You should set the scripts as a dependency of your script (pluginAdminPage), not the style.

Comment: @SeanDezoysa Does this solve your problem now? The `wp_register_script()` part from your question is missing, so I had to assume how you're registering it

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script()` will also register the script file if argument 2 lists the path. I'll accept your answer now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by enqueuing underscore as a dependency of the js file:

```
function loadAdminScripts() {    
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'pluginAdminPage', 
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'pluginAdminPage.js',
    ['jquery', 'underscore']
    );
  }
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'loadAdminScripts');
```

Comment: Maybe better suggest an edit to the already given answer. Simply edit it and it will be queued for review.